# Core Data Error Code 11 and CloudError Code 6

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, icloud

I have a fully functional app in the **AppStore** with `CoreData` and `iCloud` sync. I'm testing against iOS 9 and while everything does seem to work, I notice the following errors when essentially synching from one device to another.

```
CoreData: error: (11) Fatal error.  The database at /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/580557C7-73AC-4AF8-91CF-01BD5F27ABB4/Documents/CoreDataUbiquitySupport/mobile~36705781-84CA-4F2F-9ACF-CE09430CD443/xxxCloud/480AE190-0402-423E-83C2-FACB7B4F91B0/store/xxxiCloud.sqlite is corrupted.  SQLite error code:11, 'database disk image is malformed'

CoreData: error: (NSFetchedResultsController) object <Transaction: 0x150b4a710> (entity: Transaction; id: 0xd000000010080018 <x-coredata://CDF5586C-0200-4BCB-9712-9F1B9658120B/Transaction/p1026> ; data: {
```

returned nil value for section name key path '`sectionDateFormatter`'. `Object` will be placed in unnamed section

```
[PFUbiquityFilePresenter processPendingURLs]_block_invoke(447): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Librarian returned a serious error for starting downloads Error Domain=BRCloudDocsErrorDomain Code=6 "Path is outside of any CloudDocs container, will never sync" UserInfo={NSDescription=Path is outside of any CloudDocs container, will never sync, NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5BCFB5C2-3362-4CEB-B3D1-1D9F26E8BED7/Documents/CoreDataUbiquitySupport/mobile~CCC51F1A-17CD-4ECE-9139-5541E004AB6F/EnvyCloud/B7952C69-736E-45B9-91FF-BCF559E3C4D6/container/mobile~CCC51F1A-17CD-4ECE-9139-5541E004AB6F/EnvyCloud/WVf0Dg3x4aqbEj~WvOz9p4_uNDY2us3DJ3aK0MihPb8=/73F3E0C0-9B6D-4A81-84A7-7FC93A7351E6.1.cdt} with userInfo {
```

Now these errors do not always occur; I can't seem to find a pattern to reproduce it but it's occurred enough times to worry me. What exactly is going on with these errors? I can see with the first, it looks like it's corrupted, but how does something like that even happen?

I've never seen these errors on iOS 7 or iOS 8 and it's just appearing in XCode 7 beta 5 when I run on my iOS 9 device, sometimes (it doesn't always occur).

Comment: Make sure you get the very latest versions of iOS9, OSX 10.11 and XCode beta - there still problems in the Beta's but most seem to be resolved in the very latest versions, in particular the very latest XCode update.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you ever find out what was going on? This is only happening to me if Address Sanitizer is turned on!